# R: is fisher's exact test with large numbers still accurate?

Tags: r

I have a 2x2 table like this and i want to do Fisher's exact test on it to test if the overlap between two sets is significant.

As you can see, I have a very large number at 2.2e9, which exceeds the limit of the largest number a 32 bit R can handle.

```
    yes no
yes 127437282   364949163
no  188213539   2200433302
```

I got around this with bit64 package and us as.integer64(). I then run a Fisher's exact test:

```
    fisher<-function(n1,n2,n3,n4,fname){
    library(bit64)
    n1n<-as.integer(n1)
    n2n<-as.integer(n2)
    n3n<-as.integer(n3)
    n4n<-as.integer64(n4)
    testor=rbind(c(n1n,n2n),c(n3n,n4n))
    x<-fisher.test(testor)
    print("sample name")
    print(fname)
    print("data is")
    print(testor)
    print("fisher's exact test result is")
    x
}
fisher(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)
```

The result is this:

```
          [,1]          [,2]
[1,] 127437282  3.649492e+08
[2,] 188213539 1.086944e-314
[1] "fisher's exact test result is"

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  
p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0000000000 0.0001190186
sample estimates:
odds ratio
         0
```

Somehow, the large number 2200433302 became 1.086944e-314. Why did this happen?

Also, the calculation took more than 5 minutes to finish, which is way too slow. I'm not sure if it makes sense to do such a calculation with large numbers? Is there some way to transform the input data and still maintain its validity?

Thanks!

Comment: this doesnt address your question at all but this is an interesting link http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/given-the-power-of-computers-these-days-is-there-ever-a-reason-to-do-a-chi-squa?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Why on earth would you do a fisher's exact test for this? That test is better suited for small counts. Wouldn't a chi-squared test be more appropriate??

Comment: 1.086944e-314 is effectively 0.

Comment: @MrFlick i realized that chi-squared test is better for Fisher's exact test.. i just didn't know before. However, the problem still persist with the 2.2e9 became a really small number. I guess it's still the issue with large number in 32 bit R..

Comment: You gave us no details about how you made this "conversion". What makes you think that `fisher.test` will accept an integer that is larger than `.Machine$integer.max` in any representation?

Comment: Significance/hypothesis testing with such large numbers is ridiculous. You have an odds ratio of `4.082 (95%CI = 4.081 - 4.083)`. If someone wants to significance check that they are lacking in interpretation skills.

Comment: @BondedDust yep, I really don't know fisher.test would accept number that large, i guess it doesn't.. just updated the question

Comment: @thelatemail so OR of 4.082 is very significant in all cases?  i really need to study statistics..

Comment: @olala - no, but it almost certainly is when you are talking about half a billion cases. Notice that the Fisher test is checking if the "true odds ratio is not equal to 1". I'd be pretty confident after sampling 632 million cases that there's a difference with an odds ratio > 4.

Comment: E.g. - take `test <- matrix(c(4,1,1,1),nrow=2)` - odds ratio = 4, but 95% confidence interval = 0.11 - 137, because you only have 7 cases. Certainty of a point estimate (odds ratio in this instance) will vary dramatically dependent on sample size.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that using pkg:bit64 provides a reliable basis for calculation. Even basic tests of order fail:

This is the test in fisher test:

```
>  any( c(1,1,1, n4n) > .Machine$integer.max)
[1] FALSE
```

I think that integer64 values are getting implicitly coerced to `numeric` values and then then getting inappropriately interpreted in this case as a very small numeric value 'numeric' or 'doubles' are 53 bits for the "a" portion and most of the remaining 11 bits for the power of 10. Notice what happens with the number "1" coerced from integer64 to numeric by `c()`.

```
> b <- as.integer64(1)
> c(1,b)
[1]  1.000000e+00 4.940656e-324
```

This is designed to show that putting "integer64" objects in simple structures created problems:

```
> c(1,1,1, n4n)[4] > .Machine$integer.max
[1] FALSE
>  n4n > .Machine$integer.max
[1] TRUE
```

The problem is that in order for an 'integer64' to be handled by `c.integer64` and `>.integer64` correctly there needs to be an `integer64` classed object as the first item. (These are after S3 methods, so they take their class dispatch only from the first argument.)

```
> c(n4n, 1,1,1, n4n)[5] > .Machine$integer.max
[1] TRUE
```

Notice that swapping the 1,1 location with the 2,2 location should give the same result.

```
> fisher( 2200433302,   364949163, 188213539, 127437282, "no_op")
Error in fisher.test(testor) : 
  all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
In addition: Warning message:
In fisher(2200433302, 364949163, 188213539, 127437282, "no_op") :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

And changing the values to all be coerced to integer64 does not prevent problems:

```
 fisher<-function(n1,n2,n3,n4,fname){
     library(bit64)
     n1n<-as.integer64(n1)
     n2n<-as.integer64(n2)
     n3n<-as.integer64(n3)
     n4n<-as.integer64(n4)
     testor=rbind(c(n1n,n2n),c(n3n,n4n))
     x<-fisher.test(testor)
     print("sample name")
     print(fname)
     print("data is")
     print(testor)
     print("fisher's exact test result is")
     x
   }

fisher( 2200433302,   364949163, 188213539, 127437282, "no_op")
# Error in fisher.test(testor) : 'x' has entries too large to be integer
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. i guess there is no way to do this with number this large in R. Can I divide all the input counts by 10 and then do a Chi square test? or is there some way to do proportion test?